# the aa-enforce command for apparmor results in a "command not found" error

Tags: apparmor

I am trying to enable the `apparmor` profile for `firefox`, but when i enter

```
sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

i get a `aa-enforce command not found` message.

`apparmor_status` indicates `apparmor` is running with 20 profiles loaded.

any ideas? it's Ubuntu 14.04 & i just installed it

Comment: Have you installed the package `apparmor-profiles`  ?

Comment: no, i didn't think this is required - usr.bin.firefox is already in the apparmor profiles folder

Comment: Maybe try to install the package ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/aa-enforce` is part of the package `apparmor-utils`, which isn't installed per default.

Therefore install the package with

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: thanks Fabby - that did the trick. I didn't see this requirement anywhere in the documentation - would have thought it would be here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor in the installation section